# Heap Analytics in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, analytics

Currently working on a Chrome extension that requires Heap analytics. I can see that Heap is being setup correctly with the load script provided, and I can see in network tab of Chrome's developer tools that messages are being sent to `heapanalytics.com`. Only problem is that this is not showing up in Heap's interface.

Here is my identify and user properties code:

```
heap.identify("user@example.com");
window.heap.addUserProperties({'Plugin': 'gmail'});
```

Here is my track code:

```
heap.track("EmailSent", {
    plugin: "gmail",
    tracked: true,
    linkIncluded: true,
    oneRecipient: true,
    toggle: true
});
```

Comment: For future readers - The problem appeared to be where I was running the code. I now have it in a background script and (after tweaking the plugin's content security policy to allow the heap code to be loaded) it works.

Comment: can you please share how did you get it work. I am stuck in a similar problem where heap doesn't show the data I send.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions with manifest v3 (v2 is [sunsetting](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate/mv2-deprecation-timeline#:%7E:text=Upcoming-,June%202024%3A%20Chrome%20MV2%20deprecation%20pre%2Dstable%20rollout,in%20Chrome%20127%20and%20later.)) cannot load third party scripts for analytics purposes as [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate#remotely-hosted-code) implies. So you cannot integrate the simple HeapJs client but use the [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/how-to/integrate/google-analytics-4#measurement-protocol).